# UIButton accepting only double click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I am showing a `UITableView` when user tap the `UIButton`. If the user tapped the `UIButton` second time `UITableView` should be off. so i wrote below code but it is accepting only double click.

in .h `BOOL selected;`

in .m

```
-(void)ShowTable {
    if (selected)
    {
            aTableview=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 280, 128, 140)];
            aTableview.dataSource=self;
            aTableview.delegate=self;
            [scrollView addSubview:aTableview];

           [aTableview setHidden:NO];
            selected = NO;
        } else {
                [aTableview setHidden:YES];
                selected= YES;
        }
}
```

Comment: 1) Where is this code? 2) Why do you add the table view to two parent views? Only the 2nd one will be used.

Comment: pch .. i need to show yar .. i am mentioned the code for tableview.. read the question completely

Comment: @iOSDeveloper You still didn't show us where the posted code is. What method is it in? We know it's in a .m file. That's not specific enough.

Comment: i think your problem is when you connect this method with that to the Button. Please post that code for more clarity please

Comment: Or you cold play with the UI. Add two buttons, one ontop of the other. Hide the first button when the user clicks the button, revealing the second button. When the second button is tapped, you can off the uitableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare the one `Bool` Value in your.h file, in this `Bool` Value default in `0`

```
int selected;
```

.m file

```
-(void)ShowTable {

 switch (selected) {
    case 0:
       aTableview=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 280, 128, 140)];
        aTableview.dataSource=self;
        aTableview.delegate=self;
        [scrollView addSubview:aTableview];


        selected=1;
        break;
    case 1:
         [aTableview setHidden:YES];
        selected=0;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add button in your view and give connection of it.

In your `ViewController.h` file

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *btn;
```

and `ViewController.m` file add Tapgesture in your button

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapBehind:)];

    [recognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];

    recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    [btn addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

TapGesture Method.

```
- (void)handleTapBehind:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@" == Double Click");
}
```

Double click on your button and get log below:

[image]

Comment: ur answer is very closer to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

in your viewDidLoad method -

```
selected    =   YES;
aTableview=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 280, 128, 140)];
aTableview.dataSource=self;
aTableview.delegate=self;
[scrollView addSubview:aTableview];
[aTableview setHidden:YES];

aTableview.layer.cornerRadius=7.0f;
aTableview.layer.borderWidth=0.5f;
aTableview.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
```

And change ShowTable as -

```
-(void)ShowTable {
    if (selected)
    {
        [aTableview setHidden:NO];
        selected = NO;
    } else {
        [aTableview setHidden:YES];
        selected= YES;
    }
}
```

as per the code tableview will be hidden initially and on button tap it will show.
May this will solve your problem

Comment: can you provide the code how you are adding button and calling ShowTable method

Answer (score 0):

You can try change code a little bit

```
if (aTableView.hidden) {
     //prepare table
    [aTableView setHidden:NO];
} else {
    [aTableViewSetHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that IBAction touchUpInside is assigned to your button. I have modified your method. Take a look.

```
- (IBAction)toggleTableViewVisibility:(id)sender 
{
    selected = !selected;
    [self ShowTable];
}

-(void)ShowTable {
    if (selected)
   {
     //if tableView is already is a subview of scrollView don't recreate it.
     if([aTableView superView] == scrollView)  
      {         
        aTableview=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 280, 128, 140)];
        aTableview.dataSource=self;
        aTableview.delegate=self;
        [scrollView addSubview:aTableview];
      }

        [aTableview setHidden:NO];
    } 
    else 
    {
        [aTableview setHidden:YES];    
    }
}
```